# Looking for help with implementation of a heap data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays

I have an operation on a heap, a fixdown operation .  This is the code:

```
public class Heap {

    public static void fixdown (int a[],int k,int n) {
        while (2*k<=n) {
            int j=2*k;
            if (j<n && a[j]<a[j+1]) j++;
            if (!(a[k]<a[j])) break;
            swap(a,k,j);
            k=j; 
        }
    }

    public  static void main (String[]args) {
        int a[]=new int[]{12,15,20,29,23,22,17,40,26,35,19,51};
        fixdown(a,1,a.length);
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void swap (int a[],int i,int j) {
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t;
    }
}
```

Update: I have changed it and now there is no error.

//result is

```
12
29
20
40
23
22
17
15
26
35
19
51
```

Comment: Look at fixdown and see what it is doing on just that one value. A good use for a unit test.

Comment: I recommend using more descriptive variable names.  It will help you avoid little mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines:

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
 System.out.println(a[i]);
```

suggest, that indexes in Your array are 0 based. If so, the indexes of the left and right child of the element at index i should be calculated as

```
leftchild_index = 2*i+1;
rightchild_index = 2*i+2; // rightchild_index = leftchild_index + 1
```

left child of `a[0]` is `a[1]` and the right one is `a[2]`

If parameter n is the length of an array containing the heap, You need to fix some conditions

```
while(2*k<=n){
```

should be changed to:

```
while(2*k + 1 < n){
```

and

```
int j=2*k;
    if (j<n && a[j]<a[j+1])   j++;
```

should be changed to

```
int j = 2 * k + 1;
    if (j < n - 1 && a[j] < a[j+1])   j++;
```

Otherwise You are accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: You could also describe right as rightchild = leftchild + 1; ^^

Answer (score 1):

`a[j]=k;`

You probably want:

`a[j]=t;`

---

#### On array declarations

Please, please, do not make a habit of declaring arrays like this:

```
int x[];
```

You should instead put the brackets with the *type*, rather than with the *identifier*:

```
int[] x;
```

#### Related questions

- [Is there any difference between `Object[] x` and `Object x[]` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229602/is-there-any-difference-between-object-x-and-object-x)
- [Difference between `int[] myArray` and `int myArray[]` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454921/difference-between-int-myarray-and-int-myarray-in-java)
- [in array declaration `int[] k,i` and `int k[],i`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102703/in-array-declaration-int-k-i-and-int-k-i)

  - These declarations result in different types for `i`!

Comment: polygenelubricants  please look at my output i am sure it is correct but can u advise me or check?

Comment: re: arrays - While I personally use `type[] ident;` for my declarations, and I do see where it is cited that it is "convention", would you care to elaborate on the rationale behind it? I happened to have picked it up the "right way", but I don't see a logical reason why it would be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

you have `a[j]=k;`

perhaps it should be `a[j]=t;`

Answer (score 0):

The code is very hard to read in its current state of indentation, but I believe `a[j]=k;`
 should be `a[j]=t;`.