# Question about in-place sort

Tags: algorithm

For example, we have the following array:

```
char data[]=new char[]{'A','S','O','R','T','I','N','G','E','X','A','M','P','L','E'};
```

and an index array:

```
int  a[]=new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};

void insitu (char data[], int a[], N)
{
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        char v=data[i];
        int j, int k;
        for (k = i; a[k] != i; k = a[j], a[j]=j)
        {
            j=k;
            data[k]=data[a[k];
        }
        data[k]=v;
        a[k]=k;
    }
}
```

My question is what `j` should be initialized to.  When I run this code, it asks me to initialize `j`; what should I do?

Comment: `for (k=i;a[k]!=i;k=a[j];a[j]=j)` this line can't compile. You have 4 parts here.

Comment: This line can't compile either `data[k]=data[a[k];`.

Comment: please mark your questions as a homework, this is clearly not for production

Comment: so this code has many bugs yes?    what is correct form?

Comment: @davit-datuashvili what is it then?

Comment: from book algorithm in c++  author robert sedgewick

Comment: @davit-datuashvili well homework is generic term for learning tasks. so this **is** learning task

Comment: ok as u want :) and so what is mistake in my code and how correct it?

Comment: Please try and format your code correctly - it makes it a lot easier to read and debug.

Comment: @davit: You are insulting us by writing a crappy code and expecting us to fix it. Put some effort into your own work.

Comment: no   not insulting  just ask if it is possible correct it  ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Java implementation of the in-place sort in Sedgewick's Algorithms in C++ ([see page](http://books.google.co.id/books?id=UD6wGr5-_1MC&lpg=PA306&ots=fGPnWlCYk_&dq=sedgewick%20insitu%20sort&pg=PA306#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

```
public class InSitu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 0, 10, 8, 14, 7, 5, 13, 11, 6, 2, 12, 3, 1, 4, 9 };
        char[] data = { 'A', 'S', 'O', 'R', 'T', 'I', 'N', 'G',
            'E', 'X', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'L', 'E' };
        insitu(data, a, a.length);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));
        // prints "[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]"
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(data));
        // prints "[A, A, E, E, G, I, L, M, N, O, P, R, S, T, X]"
    }
    static void insitu(char[] data,int[] a, int N) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            char v = data[i];
            int j, k;
            for (k=i; a[k] != i; k = a[j], a[j] = j) {
                j = k;
                data[k] = data[a[k]];
            }
            data[k] = v;
            a[k] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### On array declarations

Please, please, do not make a habit of declaring arrays like this:

```
int x[];
```

You should instead put the brackets with the *type*, rather than with the *identifier*:

```
int[] x;
```

#### Related questions

- [Is there any difference between `Object[] x` and `Object x[]` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229602/is-there-any-difference-between-object-x-and-object-x)
- [Difference between `int[] myArray` and `int myArray[]` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454921/difference-between-int-myarray-and-int-myarray-in-java)
- [in array declaration `int[] k,i` and `int k[],i`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102703/in-array-declaration-int-k-i-and-int-k-i)

  - These declarations result in different types for `i`!

---

#### On definite assignment

The compiler is smart enough to know when a local variable is definitely assigned, taking into account loop constructs, etc.

The following code compiles:

```
        int local;
        do {
            local = 0;
        } while (local != 0);
```

While this doesn't:

```
        int local;
        while (local != 0) { // doesn't compile!
            local = 0;
        }
```

Similarly, this compiles:

```
        for (int local; ; local++) {
            local = 0;
        }
```

This is because of the semantics of `for` loop, where the loop body (`local = 0;`) precedes the loop update (`local++`) in the control flow, even though it may not look like it in the text.

The specification doesn't allow the compiler to be *too* smart; for example the following doesn't compile:

```
    boolean b = false; // or whatever
    int local;
    if (b) {
        local = 0;
    }
    if (!b) {
        local = 1;
    }
    local++; // doesn't compile!
```

But this does:

```
    boolean b = false; // or whatever
    int local;
    if (b) {
        local = 0;
    } else {
        local = 1;
    }
    local++;
```

#### See also

- [JLS 16 Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html)

Comment: The java compiler will let you use `j` before it's initialized?

Comment: Java gives all variables a default value. The declaration *is* the initialization. This is defined in the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#10935 . See simpler explanation here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. So in this case, `j` is equal to `0`.

Comment: I don't see anything assigning a value to `j` before this `k = a[j]`, or does that piece get executed after the loop body runs through once?

Comment: @jasonmp85: Class scope, you're right, method scope I'm pretty sure you're wrong.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: see latest revision.

Comment: You're right, my JLS link even says so: "A local variable (§14.4, §14.13) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified by the compiler using the rules for definite assignment (§16)." But poly's answer is still valid: `j` is assigned within the loop before the end conditional is checked, so there's no read of an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the third form when writing my infinite loops.

Comment: @davit: It sorts `a`, and moves around elements of `data` accordingly.

Comment: @polygenelubricants    data array  is sorted?but in book result is different

Comment: @davit: I've updated the answer to match the example in the book.